# terraform function on depends_on attribute

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cognito

In my TF code, I have to manage the creation of a cognito identity provider resource based on several variables.

For example:

```
resource "aws_cognito_identity_provider" "test1" {
  count = var.test1 ? 1 : 0
...
}

resource "aws_cognito_identity_provider" "test2" {
  count = var.test2 ? 1 : 0
...
}
```

This is OK but I also need to create cognito user pool client resource based on which cognito identity provider is created (needed in the depends_on block)

```
resource "aws_cognito_user_pool_client" "this" {
  name                                 = local.context.rp.cognito.user_pool_client
  user_pool_id                         = var.aws_cognito_user_pool_id
  generate_secret                      = var.generate_secret
  allowed_oauth_flows                  = var.allowed_oauth_flows
  callback_urls                        = var.callback_urls
  logout_urls                          = var.logout_urls
  allowed_oauth_scopes                 = var.allowed_oauth_scopes
  allowed_oauth_flows_user_pool_client = var.allowed_oauth_flows_user_pool_client
  supported_identity_providers         = local.supported_identity_providers
  explicit_auth_flows                  = var.explicit_auth_flows

  depends_on = [
...
  ]
}
```

I tried this, but it's not working:

```
  depends_on = [
    var.test1== true && var.test2== false ? iaws_cognito_identity_provider.test1: (var.test1 == false && var.test2 == true ? iaws_cognito_identity_provider.test2: "")
  ]
```

Do you have any suggestions to do so? Do I need to create 2 cognito user pool client resource based on these test1 and test2 vars?

Comment: Why do you need `depends_on`? What would be the full code for your `aws_cognito_user_pool_client`?

Comment: You're right, I don't really know why there is "depends_on"... it's a module that I didn't develop and it was already there, maybe i can just skip it ;)

Comment: Can you show full code for `aws_cognito_user_pool_client`? You provided only `depends_on`. What  is the rest of the definition?

Comment: just add it now

Comment: I don't see the point in `depends_on`. Did you try without it? Do you get any errors?

Comment: I'll give it a try

Comment: It seems to be OK, thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, it was determined that `depends_on` is not needed in the current setup. Thus it was removed, and no new problems have been found.